# Destructor crash

Tags: c++, destructor

I am working on a Win32 c++ application in Visual studio.

In one of the source files, I have global object like below.

```
TestClass tObj;

int main() //Execution starts here
{
}
```

TestClass is defined in other DLL like below.

```
struct Source
{

};

class TestClass
{
  list<Source> sourceList;
    public:
         TestClass() {}
        ~TestClass() {}
};
```

While my application is running, if i try to close the app explicitly,
by closing the console window, it is crashing in TestClass destructor.
Callstack shows CrtIsValidHeapPointer is failing.

Pls help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Use four spaces to indent code and none for normal text.

Comment: Have you built the exe and the DLL with the same C++ runtime?

Comment: Yes i built both with Visual studio. Only configuration type is different. One is exe and other is DLL configuration in Project settings.

Comment: how do you link your dll to exe ? by conventional static-linking (use of .lib)

Comment: Crash is solved by using Same runtime library in exe and dll.
Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you build bot the EXE and the DLL with the same runtime, preferably with the dynamic runtime.

Comment: Crash is solved by using Same runtime library in exe and dll. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that differing compiler/linker settings between the .exe and .dll are effectively causing the .dll and .exe to be using different implementations of the standard library:

- You must use the same preprocessor flags* to build both the .exe and the .dll, otherwise each binary will compile with subtly different implementations.
- You must link both both the .exe and the .dll to the dynamic runtime. Binaries linked statically to the runtime get their own heap - and you end up allocating on one heap and trying to free on another.

To fix this, go to `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation` and change the runtime library option to `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`. You must do this for both the .exe project and the .dll project.

As of Visual Studio 2010, some of these kind of errors will be detected at link time using [#pragma detect_mismatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956429.aspx).

*<sub>For all preprocessor flags that have any effect of the standard library implementation</sub>

Comment: `+1` from me for this comprehensive answer. @bjskishore123: Please read the the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You are encouraged to accept the answer which you feel helped you the most to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is crashing in the destructor, an exception is being thrown from the destructor which is calling terminate and crashing your application.[Uncaught exceptions](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm)

> There are two situations in which a destructor is called. The first is when an object is destroyed under "normal" conditions, e.g., when it goes out of scope or is explicitly deleted. The second is when an object is destroyed by the exception-handling mechanism during the stack-unwinding part of exception propagation. You must write your destructors under the conservative assumption that an exception is active, because if control leaves a destructor due to an exception while another exception is active, C++ calls the terminate function

Comment: Global object is getting constructed before main() gets called.
So i think, its destruction is happening after main() exits.
That time, the list<Source> sourceList head that STL internally uses, is not valid at the time of freeing. Hence CrtIsValidHeapPointer is failing.

Comment: The question is: why is the sourceList head invalid? If your exe & DLL are correctly built with compatible runtimes, then this code should work fine. The runtime will clean up global objects before the heap is freed.

Comment: Crash is solved by using Same runtime library in exe and dll.
Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Global objects are initialised and destroyed by the C runtime. They are initialised before `main` is called and destroyed after it returns.

The error is probably caused by something that is being accessed from your `TestClass` destructor (or indirectly from a `Source` destructor). The destructor code is accessing invalid memory (or memory that has already been freed).

The order of initialisation and destruction of global variables is not defined, and is frequently a source of errors on application termination. If there are other globals that might clean up or modify resources referenced by TestClass, then this could be the culprit.

Comment: I am not adding any node to the sourceList(list<Source>).
List is empty at the time of destructor call.
But still, STL List will have a hidden Head pointer internally. While trying to free that, its crashing.

Comment: Which CRT(s) are you building the EXE and the DLL against?

Answer (score 0):

Are the DLL and the EXE built using the same alignment (pack pragma)?

Answer (score 0):

try to make your constructor and destructor non-inline, it may help. If ctor and dtor are not inline, both will be generated on behalf of dll, so construction and  destruction of list<> will be executed with the same runtime library.
Generally, try to avoid passing opaque stl objcts across dll boundaries. It is better to incapsulate them as privatte members into your own classes and provide non-inlined methods to manipulate such a members